# Is there an official translation for oleogustus, yet?

Tags: translation

**io9**

> There are five acknowledged tastes: sweet, sour, bitter, salty, and (slightly more controversially) umami. For awhile now, researchers have suggested the existence of a sixth taste: fat. Now, a new study has researchers saying they may have finally isolated it—and they’ve given it a name: oleogustus.

**oleogustus** in Chinese news media is usually written in English with a parenthetically explanation something along the lines of:

> oleogustus(在拉丁语中意思是脂肪味)

- is there an official translation yet?

Although I'm only expecting it to be something like 脂味.

Comment: There are roughly 20 pages on .cn TLD sites  [Google for 'site:cn oleogustus'] that mention this word, which itself is probably not older than 2 weeks or so. Relax.

Comment: 油味儿？...........

Comment: Informally they are called 腻.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's translated as:

> 脂肪味

Sources:

> http://news.sciencenet.cn/htmlnews/2015/7/323886.shtm
>
> http://politics.people.com.cn/n/2015/0729/c70731-27376218.html

Baike has an [article](http://www.baike.com/wiki/%E8%84%82%E8%82%AA%E5%91%B3) on it too, but that seems to be related to an earlier US finding related to the gene CD36.

Interestingly, your suggestion of `脂味` appears to be the [preferred](http://headlines.yahoo.co.jp/hl?a=20150727-00000090-it_nlab-sci) Japanese translation.